# Why are power cells unavailable for the Ancient Armory side quest after finishing the main quest?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I finished the main quest, and am now attempting to complete the Ancient Armory side quest. I had found only 2 of the power cells, so I'm re-visiting the places where the power cells are supposed to be located, however they are not there.  Specifically, I've gone back to the All-Mother Temple and Grave Hoard and found the exact spots but no power cell.

Are you supposed to be able to collect the power cells after completing the main quest?

EDIT:

My question is not about the power cell locations, I know where they are.  This is about why they aren't there.

Also, I'm on the PS4.

EDIT #2:

I closed the application and restarted the game from my last save.  This is *after* the main quest has been completed.  I went back to the All Mother Temple, and confirmed that the power cell is not in the secret room where it should be.  See attached photos:

1. Map showing All Mother Temple
2. Map showing the hidden room where the power cell should be
3. The hidden room where the power cell should be
4. Quest status showing that I had already collected two power cells

[image: Map showing All Mother Temple]
[image: Map showing the hidden room where the power cell should be]
[image: The hidden room where the power cell should be]
[image: Quest status showing that I had already collected two power cells]

Comment: They are all still accessible after the main quest. Are you sure that these specific power cells are the ones you're missing?

Comment: Maker’s End was the one I missed to begin with, but they can all be found after the main quest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I find the power cells to restore the bunker door in “Ancient armory”?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303559/where-do-i-find-the-power-cells-to-restore-the-bunker-door-in-ancient-armory)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the locations I mentioned were NOT where I picked up the two power cells.  I got them in the Underground Bunker and Maker's End.  Let me try exiting the game from the main menu to see if that helps.

Comment: Have you gone back to the other two locations and checked? you may be mis-remembering which ones you have already picked up.

Comment: As I said, I have only two power cells, and I know exactly where I got them: the Underground Bunker, and Maker's End (during the quest).  This feels like I missed the chance to get them, even though everyone says otherwise.

Comment: Note that I've also returned to the Grave Hoard, and its power cell was also missing.  I'm not wasting any more time checking other locations.  I'll probably have to start a new game if I want to get that armor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, this is a [known bug](https://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/Horizon-Zero-Dawn/Ancient-Armory-power-cell-glitch/m-p/24963488/highlight/true) that has still not been patched.

And it's not specifically related to finishing the main quest.